# how to restrict users from pressing keyboard buttons in win forms

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I am making a winforms app for a public kiosk,so the users need to sign in to use the pc.
but i don't know how can i block the users from pressing keyboard keys that will get the ability for the users to use the pc without login,for example by pressing windows + alt and creating a new desktop or other ways,any help will be appreciated

Comment: it's too hard. it's the os controlls the app, not the other way around.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175675/blocking-shortcut-keys-using-c-sharp

Comment: [Set up a single-app kiosk on Windows 10/11](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/kiosk-single-app)