# How do I trap windows key, alt+tab, ctrl+alt+delete in C#?

Tags: c#, keyboard-hook

How do I trap <kbd>Windows</kbd> key, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> in a Windows application using C#?

Comment: Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292165/how-to-trap-the-keyboard-strokes-on-a-c-win-forms-application-ctrl-alt-del http://stackoverflow.com/questions/886076/how-can-i-intercept-all-key-events-including-ctrlaltdel-and-ctrltab

Comment: Yeah, but the original questions didn't use the cool `<kbd>` tags!

Comment: I would recommend that you DON'T do this, if at all possible.  When I press those keys, I'm expecting certain behavior, and if an application that I'm using prevented that  behavior, I'd be upset.

Comment: @Matt Grande: Sometimes what is required is not what the user wants.  For instance, this exact behavior is often required for kiosk software.

Answer (score 5):

You can capture Ctrl-Alt-Delete. But you need to implement your own [GINA dll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380543(VS.85).aspx) which is loaded by Winlogon.

You'll need to code this up in C or C++ as it needs to be a native DLL.

Answer (score 4):

As Jan stated, you can't capture CTRL-ALT-DEL without writing your own GINA.

For the Windows or ALT-TAB keys, you can look at these for help:

[Capturing Keystrokes without Focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161053/capturing-keystrokes-without-focus) (SO near-duplicate)

[How To Set A Windows Hook](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318804)

[Hooks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632589.aspx) (low-level, but will explain what you need for the P/Invoke)

Answer (score 1):

Almost by definition, you [can't](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-Alt-Delete#Windows_Vista_and_later) "trap" ctrl-alt-delete.

Comment: Yes, you can (using a custom GINA). But not in C#.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> cannot be captured using an application.

See this question to get some more idea: [How to trap the keyboard strokes on a c# win forms application (CTRl + alt +Del)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292165/how-to-lock-the-keyboard-and-mouse-for-a-windows-application-c)

Answer (score 1):

Some Remote Management Software and Virtual Machines do this. If you press [CTRL]+[ALT]+[DEL] the specific Windows Dialog will still opens, but the Application also displays, that you have pressed [CTRL]+[ALT]+[DEL] and probably wanted it t become effective on the Target Machine and not your host. It seams rather easy to capture these keys, but cancelling the Event may be harder.

Comment: That's not an answer to the question at all.